# How iphone Contacts locate the address in google map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, street-address

I was trying to show the address in google map in my iphone app.
I tried to use

```
NSString * theAddressString =......;
NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@",theAddressString];
NSString * urlString = [query stringByAddingPercetntEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Google map can not find some addresses we provided.(Some Japanese or Chinese addresses) But if I saved the address to iPhone contacts. And then pressed
the contact's address link. It will jump to google maps,though google map first alerted that "can not locate the address", after I confirmed the alert message, another view would display the location in the google map or show the address in the nearby.

So iPhone's "Contact" app may use other apis to filter the address string to locate the address or using some king of "fuzzy search".

Does anybody know how do they achieve it?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following one and let me about the status of solution.

```
    NSString * theAddressString =......; 
    NSString *latlong = [[myLatitude stringByAppendingString:@","]stringByAppendingString:myLongitude];
    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@@%@",[theAddressString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    //NSString * urlString = [query stringByAddingPercetntEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

**New Code with give address:**

```
    NSString *theAddressString = @"東村山市野口町1-3-49 アマドムス 102, 東京都, 日本";
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[theAddressString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];  
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
    float latitude=0.0; 
    float longitude=0.0;    
    if([listItems count] >=4  && [ [listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]){        
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];       
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];      
    }   
    else{       
        NSLog(@"Error");        
    }   
    NSString *myLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
    NSString *myLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitude];
    NSString *latlong = [[myLatitude stringByAppendingString:@","]stringByAppendingString:myLongitude];
    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@@%@",[theAddressString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [latlong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]];
```

I have checked the **query** string with google map and it is showing me the pin in Google map.

Comment: Google map could not show the address as well.

I check the string in the google map, it is the same as when I press the address in the iPhone's Contacts.

Comment: Please check again with given code, as you have to pass latitude and longitude with address.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to process the input address string which does not provide with latitude and longitude.

Comment: My problem is:I want to know how apple's Contact app call Google map's API to locate the address?

For example:
Type the following string:
"東村山市野口町1-3-49 アマドムス 102  東京都 日本" in the google maps' search field.
It will not show the address.

But if you create a new contact, and put the address string to the corresponding field:
country:日本 city:東京都 street:東村山市野口町1-3-49 アマドムス 102. And press the address in the contact, the google map will show the address. And the search field's text in the google map is the same as the first try above.

Does anybody know the trick apple knows?

Comment: I have posted a latest code and have checked it with Google Map in safari and it is showing the location. Try it..

Comment: Thank you.
The updated code did improve, but there are still some addresses
The above code could not locate.  (Could not get the latitude and longitude)
But if  I put in iPhone's contact app 's street field. It could.
For example:
本社〒104 東京都中央区八丁堀 4-5-4秀和桜橋ビンレ4F
So may be there are still some tricks, may be I should look trough google map APIs.

Comment: If you have follow the code carefully, I have already posted the code to get latitude and longitude with the help of address. With this code, there is nothing as such missing to stop you to reach your destination now.

Comment: Thank you, I really did follow the code, but for some address as mentioned above, It could not get the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Well, I don't know why is the given code for mentioned address not working at your end but I have tested the code with the same address and it is returning latitude and longitude too.